# Sum of all terms in convolution of the permutation of 1 to n

Tags: number-theory

Find all the permutation of 1 to $n$ and treat the $n$ numbers produced as a series
and find their sums.  What is the total of all $n!$ sums?  Example for 1,2,3 gives
one of six permutation 2,1,3: convolving gives $3*3 + (1*3+3*1) + (2*3+1*1+3*2)=9 + 6 + 13 = 28$.  The total for the six permutations of 1 to 3 is 144 and for 1 to 4 
is 1480.  It seems that the only way to find this sum is by laborious additions by considering all the cases.  Can anyone think of a shortcut?

I will give another example and hope the machine prints what I want it to print.  Take 1,2,3,4 which has 24 permutations and select 2,4,1,3.  Try to visualize that these numbers are vertical and that I am convolving them to get for the first column 2 4 1 3*3; 2nd 2 4 1*3 3*1; 3rd 2 4*3 1*1 3*4; 4th 2*3 4*1 1*4 3*2. Add the sum of the products 3*3 + 1*3 + 3*1 + 4*3 1*1 3*4 2*3 + 4*1 + 1*4 + 3*2 and you get 60.  If this does not make it clear, I can do no better with the limitations of what the machine wants to send to you.

Comment: How do you go from $1,2,3$ to $2,1,4$, and what does "convolving" mean ?

Comment: Pardon the mistake from a very noisy public library.  Follow the example to see the definition of convolving, as in A000292 for the convolution of the

Comment: the natural numbers to get 1,4,10,20....

Comment: in the example you give (1,2,3),(2,1,3), isn't convolution equal to (1*2+2*1+3*3),(2*2+3*1), (3*2), which sums to 26 ?

Comment: "and find their sums": the sum of all permutations of the sequence {1,2,..,n} is the same, the number of permutations is know, so the total is an obvious calculation. I think something is missing here.

Comment: Convolution of (1,2,3) with himself is (9,12,10,4,1)

Comment: No it isn't.  It is simply 6 * 6.

Comment: I am convolving 2,1,3 with itself.

Comment: In your first sentence, it is "the $n!$ (factorial $n$) "numbers""

Comment: Each of the permutations gives a sum of the three numbers in the sequence produced for each of the six permutations.  Think of 2,1,3 with 3,1,2 passing over it: 3*(2+1+3) 1*(1+2)+2*3 to give 3*6 + 1*4 + 2*3 =28.  It would be easier to illustrate in a short video, for I've never seen an example of taking the sequence of three terms produced and treating it as a series to be added.

Comment: I am looking for the sum after I've convolved a permutation.  See the example to see what I mean. Convolving three terms with themselves will give three terms, which I am adding to get their sum.  See A000292 for an example of an infinite sequence being produced; mine are all finite sequence having only three terms, which can be summed.

Comment: The machine did not print what I wanted it to print.  I'll try agian.

Comment: The edit does not make this any clearer---I still have no idea what you are trying to ask...

Comment: It is obvious that NO one here ever thought of simply adding the terms produced by a convolution of a finite list of integers.  I may as well try to put speech into print by writing a term paper on how to replace the clutch disk on a 1947 Plymouth: it is easier done than said.  Thus I will ask that you remove this question while I  put it into a totally different form.  It will be entitled "Finding the coefficients of a quadratic from all permutations of a list of consecutive integers."

Answer (score 2):

Convolution can be expressed by multiplication of polynomials. For example, $$(2x^2+x+3)^2=4x^4+4x^3+13x^2+6x+9$$
gives $[2,1,3]*[2,1,3]=[13,6,9]$ by the last $3$ coefficients. In general, we may use the coefficients of $1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}$ to formulate the convolution of sequences of length $n$.

So the polynomial
$$P(x):=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(i)x^{n-i}\biggr)^2$$
contains all the information we need. It is easy to see that $\deg P=2n-2$. We may assume that $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{2n-2}a_ix^i$ and we need to compute $S:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$.

Let $\tau\in S_n$ be the reflection $\tau(i)=n+1-i$, then
\begin{align}
P(x)&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(i)x^{n-i}\biggr)^2\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma\tau(i)x^{n-i}\biggr)^2\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(n+1-i)x^{n-i}\biggr)^2\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(i)x^{i-1}\biggr)^2\\
&=x^{2n-2}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(i)x^{i-n}\biggr)^2\\
&=x^{2n-2}P(1/x)
\end{align}
We know that $P(x)$ is self-reciprocal, i.e. $a_i=a_{2n-2-i}$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,2n-2$. Hence
$$S=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i=\sum_{i=n-1}^{2n-2}a_i=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i+\sum_{i=n-1}^{2n-2}a_i\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{2n-2}a_i\right).$$

In order to compute $S$, we first compute
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n-2}a_i=P(1)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(i)\biggr)^2=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\biggl(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\biggr)^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2n!}{4}.$$

For $a_{n-1}$, we have
$$a_{n-1}=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(i)\sigma(n+1-i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nij\left|\{\sigma\in S_n:\sigma^{-1}(i)+\sigma^{-1}(j)=n+1\}\right|$$
and
$$\left|\{\sigma\in S_n:\sigma^{-1}(i)+\sigma^{-1}(j)=n+1\}\right|=\begin{cases}
n(n-2)!, & \text{$n$ even and $i\neq j$}\\
0, & \text{$n$ even and $i=j$}\\
(n-1)!, & \text{$n$ odd}\\
\end{cases}$$
which implies
$$a_{n-1}=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{n(3n+2)(n+1)!}{12}, & \text{$n$ even}\\
\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+1)!}{4}, & \text{$n$ odd}\\
\end{cases}$$
So
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1}+\frac{n^2(n+1)^2n!}{4}\right)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{n(3n^2+6n+2)(n+1)!}{24}, & \text{$n$ even}\\
\dfrac{n(n+1)^2(n+1)!}{8}, & \text{$n$ odd}\\
\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The key in this question is a function defined on finite lists of numbers using convolution. The definition can best be seen by an example:
$$f([a,b,c,d,e])\!=\!(aa)\!+\!(ab\!+\!ba)\!+\!(ac\!+\!bb\!+\!ca)\!+\!(ad\!+\!bc\!+\!cb\!+\!da)\!+\!(ae\!+\!bd\!+\!cc\!+\!db\!+\!ea).$$
There is an alternate definition using alternating sum of squares of partial sums. Same example: $$f([a,b,c,d,e])=(a+b+c+d+e)^2-(b+c+d+e)^2+(b+c+d)^2-(c+d)^2+(c)^2.$$ The example given by the OP can be computed as $$f([2,4,1,3])\!=\!2+4+1+3)^2-(4+1+3)^2+(4+1)^2-(1)^2=10^2-8^2+5^2-1^2\!=\!60.$$
The question asks for the sequence $a(n)$ which is the sum over all permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ of $f(\pi).$ The sequence (not yet in the OEIS) begins $[1,13,144,1480,16200,183960,2257920,\dots]$ and I have no shortcut for it yet.

Comment: This occurs only once in 24 permutations: f(2,4,1,3) = f(3,1,4,2).  A lovely puzzle would be to see if it can occur with some f of the numbers 1 to n with n greater than 4 by such a reversal of the order of the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Somos's answer, we first write $a(n)$ as a sum over all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$:

$$a(n) = \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}} (-1)^{n-|S|} |S|! (n-|S|)! \big(\sum_{i\in S} i\big)^2,$$

since each $S$ occurs as a partial sum in exactly $n!/C(n,|S|) = |S|! (n-|S|)! $ permutations.  If $b(n,k,r)$ counts the number of $k$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which sum to $r$, then we can combine like terms in the above sum to get

$$a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} k!(n-k)! \sum_{r=1}^{n(n+1)/2} b(n,k,r) r^2.$$

In particular, if we have the generating function $F_{n,k}(x) = \sum_r b(n,k,r) x^r$, then $F'_{n,k}(1) = \sum_r r b(n,k,r)$ and $F''_{n,k}(1) = \sum_r r(r-1) b(n,k,r)$, so the inner sum above can be written as $F''_{n,k}(1) + F'_{n,k}(1)$.

In fact we do have a generating function for $F_{n,k}(x)$: it is given by the [$q$-binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Examples), or more specifically:

$$F_{n,k}(q) = q^{k(k+1)/2} \binom{n}{k}_q.$$

Adding this all up, if we use $\binom{n}{k}'_x$ to denote the derivative of $\binom{n}{k}_q$ with respect to $q$ evaluated at $q=x$ (similarly for higher derivatives), then:

$$a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} k!(n-k)! \left( \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} \binom{n}{k}_1 + (k^2+k+1) \binom{n}{k}'_1 + \binom{n}{k}''_1 \right).$$

Finally, $\binom{n}{k}_1$ is just the regular binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$, so we can pull it out of the sum as.

$$a(n) = n! \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}  +  \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} k!(n-k)! \left( (k^2+k+1) \binom{n}{k}'_1 + \binom{n}{k}''_1 \right).$$

The first sum can be evaluated explicitly, but it isn't very pretty (per Wolfram Alpha it's $\frac{1}{16} ( 2n^4 + 8n^3 + 8n^2 - 1 + (-1)^n)$).   Sadly, I know absolutely nothing about the properties of $\binom{n}{k}'_1$ and $\binom{n}{k}''_1$, but I'll bet someone else here does.

Comment: Splendid = dynamic breakthrough in understanding!  If you have permutations of 1 to 5 you have 120 rows with 5 entries per row to give 600 product pairs; total 16200/600 = 27 as an average for each product pair and 27 is 3 cubed.  For 1 to 7 you have 5040 rows with 7 entries per row to give 35280 product pairs and total 2257920/35280=64 which is 4 cubed.  Does this pattern continue  for 1 to n with n odd?  If so, then this is a shortcut for n odd.  Can there be one for n even?

Comment: @J.M.Bergot See Mercury's answer for an exact evaluation.  There is a lot of symmetry so we just need to keep track of how many times each product is counted.

Comment: If you make a table with 24 rows and 4 columns for all the permutations of 1 to 4 and list them in numerical order and then convolve each one with itself,,you will notice that all columns but the 3rd one have a pattern. Since 4 is an even number, that shortcut for n odd suggests that n even has no shortcut.  A similar table for 1  to 5  or 1 to 7 would be instructive to study if one has the time to produce them.  No doubt you have noticed that the factorial functioin quickly gets out of hand.